# How to restore workspace from another build in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, parent, workspace

I want to create jenkins pipeline to build my project.

One of the steps is to clone the repository, but for that I have a different job (not included in the pipeline). I would like to use a workspace of this job from the most recent successful build.

Such thing was easy to achieve by having normal maven / gradle jenkins job, but I have no idea how to do it using pipeline script.

[Example from maven job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1cS1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it's not best practice to share the workspace between 2 Jenkins pipeline jobs, you could do one thing and add a stage in the build job to do code checkout before it gets into build stage.

Your scenario can be achieved where it's a little bit complicated, you can provide a custom location for your code checkout which can be accessed in your build job. In this case, you have to think about all the scenarios like 
- how many parallel jobs you are running
- Is it possible for you to pass the checkout folder name as a variable to the build job?
- The shared location should be accessible from all the build slaves in which your build jobs are running and checkout job is running.
- handle the case to remove the checkout folder post-build job after coping build artifacts.